# Hibernate complex unique constraint

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have an entity class with the following unique constraint setup:

```
@Table(name = "foo", uniqueConstraints = {
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"service", "system", "priority", "is_default"})})
```

Where service and system are foreign keys for other entity classes, priority is an integer holding the priority of the entry among entries with the same service  and system objects and is_default is a boolean indicating a default configuration entry.

This unique constraint almost does what I want to do, but what I would need is a setup where, if is_default is `FALSE` then there can be multiple entries with the same service and system keys just with different integer priority, while if is_default is `TRUE` then there can be only 1 entry with the given service and system keys, meaning there can be only 1 default entry for a given service and system. How could I achive such a constraint?

Comment: I am afraid you have to write your own validation annotation.

Comment: thanks for the tip, i'm gonna try to understand this one then: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints

Answer (score 1):

The key is to create your own validation annotation able to validate whether the row data is unique based on a particular criteria.

Let the service iterface extend `UniqueValidated` and implement the method that performs the validation

```
public interface UniqueValidated {
     boolean isUnique(Object value, String fieldName) throws UnsupportedOperationException;
}

public interface FooService extends UniqueValidated {
    // add, delete...
}

public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {

    // add, delete...

    @Override
    public boolean isUnique(Object value, String fieldName) 
        throws UnsupportedOperationException {

        // the logic of validation itself, feel free to use DAO implementations
    }
}
```

Create the annotation that you put over the mapped attribute.

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE 
})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface Unique {
    String message() default "{validation.unique}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    Class<? extends UniqueValidated> service();
    String serviceQualifier() default "";
    String fieldName();
}
```

Finally create the class handling with the annotation.

```
public class UniqueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Unique, Object> {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private UniqueValidated service;
    private String fieldName;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Unique unique) {
        Class<? extends UniqueValidated> clazz = unique.service();
        this.fieldName = unique.fieldName();
        this.service = this.applicationContext.getBean(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object o, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (this.service == null || this.service.isUnique(o, this.fieldName)) {
            constraintValidatorContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have got inspired with the tutorial available online on the [JBoss Docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#example-implementing-classlevel-constraint). This is quite complex structure, however it leads the result well. The biggest advantage is undoubtly you can make the custom unique validation over any service implementing the `UniqueValidated`. Anyway, you need to these snippets above customize for your project.

Mapping is simple:

```
@Unique(service = FooService.class, fieldName = "theNameOfThisField"
@Column(name = "...")
private String theNameOfThisField;
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this, are you suggesting with this to put a constraint on my Service type field (which is also an entity class) inside my Foo entity class? How could I write its isUnique method for my use case, when I would need the System object as well, to query the database, and do the validation on the returned entries. I thought I would need some kind of custom constraint on the Foo class itself.

Comment: You can put the constraint to the DAO layer either or to any other class that is in touch with the database. The annotation itself doesn't do anything, there must be a layer responsible for mainly CRUD operations with the entity and it makes sense to perform validation logics within the layer.